# Получить ответ в ajax загрузке файлов

Tags: ajax, xhr

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код на отправку файлов и получения прогресса загрузки этих файлов с помощью `xhr`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://google.com/",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: "post",
    xhr: function(){
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                }
                $("#progress_upload_block div div").css("width", + percent +"%");
                /*$(".status").text(percent +"%");*/
            }, true);
        }
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == "no") {
            console.log("error");
        }
        else {
            console.log("ok");
        }
    },
});
```

На сервере код, который определяет будет ли производиться загрузка или нет.
Проблема в том что получаю этот ответ в `success` ajax и перед этим файл отправляется на `url`.
Могу ли я получить ответ от сервера перед `xhr`?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ сервера не может быть раньше окончания запроса. Потому что сервер в конце проверки файла может обнаружить какую-то ошибку, которую он не знает сначала. То есть он не может сразу выдать "OK".

А если он и без файла что-то определяет, то отправьте сначала без файла, а потом второй запрос с файлом.

Сказать неподконтрольному серверу, чтобы он быстрее выдал ответ и проигнорировал файл или загружал его на фоне, нельзя.

Это можно делать только если у вас есть контроль над сервером (если вы пишете его код). Тогда могут быть какие угодно одновременные запросы/ответы или сначала выдача информации в лёгких запросах/ответах, а потом отправка файла в следующем запросе.

Однако если вам для какого-то действия достаточно того, что сервер в принципе продолжает принимать файл, вы можете внутри слушателя `'progress'` уже выполнять какие-то действия, например показать сообщение "файл начал отправляться, значит всё идёт по плану".